# MediaRecorder.setOutputFile java.io.FileNotFoundException:: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on android 9 in android emulator

Tags: android-mediarecorder, android-9.0-pie

Android Emulator

Android Studio 4.2.1

Android:9.0

in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.androidhello">

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        ...
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ScreenRecordService" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
</manifest>
```

my customized Service class ScreenRecordService:

```
...
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
Date curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String curTime = formatter.format(curDate).replace(" ", "");
String videoQuality = "HD";
if(isVideoSd) videoQuality = "SD";
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/" + videoQuality + curTime + ".mp4");
...
```

app runs failed with below errors:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/SD2021-06-01-08-26-55.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: For sdk > 22 you have to ask runtime permissions and not only the ManifestPermissions.  I suggest you to use the easyPermission google library to help you with it: https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Comment: @BogdanAndroid , in 'private void methodRequiresTwoPermission()' this method, what should I define RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION ? because it says [Cannot resolve symbol 'RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION']. And what's the value of 'R.string.camera_and_location_rationale'

Comment: RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION should be a static final int variable, in kotlin would be a const val inside a companion object (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

before mediaRecorder.setOutputFile,ask runtime permissions.

```
String[] permissions = { Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 123);
```